# kernel oops after using aptitude

Tags: kernel

I tried to install dangerdeep using instructions given at [this site](http://dangerdeep.sourceforge.net/)
then when I tried to run this command,

```
scons debug=1 datadir=`pwd`/data
```

it gave this output:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Compiling for GNU/Linux Environment (linux2)
Using architecture: i686
Install binary path: /usr/local/bin
Using data dir: /home/anantha/dangerdeep/data
Checking for C library GL... no
Library GL is missing, it must be installed!
```

so i tried to install openGL but it returned the following:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libsdl2-dev : Depends: libudev-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So, I used aptitude.

```
sudo aptitude install libglew-dev libsdl2-dev libsdl2-image-dev libglm-dev libfreetype6-dev
```

It said, to correct some issues to successfully install those packages, it had to delete some packages. I entered `y` and it deleted those packages. After the removal, I copied the list of what it returned when they were being deleted.

**EDIT: i have placed the whole list in pasteubuntu as asked.**
i pasted the list of what appeared in the terminal while using aptitude which caused my problems- http://paste.ubuntu.com/14801048/

I went to software updater and checked to see for updates, but it asked me to do a partial upgrade because of missing packages, and I did that upgrade. I then restarted the machine and noticed that it was very slow, and 2-3 error messages popped up saying that there was a kernel oops error and I clicked on sending that report to Ubuntu community.

Now every time I try to switch the Windows b/w Firefox and Chrome, it takes a lot of time and is very slow.

Please help me correct the errors for what packages I deleted, should I install those packages again?

I thought it was a problem with refresh rate so I installed compizconfig Manager and i tried to increase the refresh rate to 160, then 200 and unchecked "Detect refresh rate". This did help a bit to increase the speed of the current window, but I still have the problem of switching windows which is very slow, please help me.

My system's specifications go as follows:

- Processor: 2x Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU T4400 @ 2.20GHz
- Memory: 2965MB (1151MB used)
- Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
- Display:

  - Resolution   : 1366x768 pixels
  - OpenGL Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.7, 128 bits)
- X11 Vendor: The X.Org Foundation
- Input Devices

  - Lid Switch
  - Power Button
  - Power Button
  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
  - USB OPTICAL MOUSE
  - SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad
  - Toshiba input device
  - USB 2.0 Camera
  - Video Bus
  - HDA Intel HDMI/DP,pcm      : 3=
  - HDA Intel Headphone
  - HDA Intel Mic
- SCSI Disks:

  - ATA TOSHIBA MK3263GS
  - TSSTcorp CDDVDW TS-L633C

Comment: please use paste.ubuntu.com for long outputs/lists.

Comment: @edward torvalds- i placed the list in the site u mentioned, thanks